# Why SerialDevice.FromIdAsync should be opened from the UI thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, win-universal-app

I'm working through the SerialArduiono example ([this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SerialArduino)). Why does they state [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SerialArduino/cs/EventHandlerForDevice.cs):

> It is important that the FromIdAsync call is made on the UI
>   thread because the consent prompt can only be displayed
>     on the UI thread.

But why? Does that mean, I can only use the serial-device in one thread? For example if I open the serialdevice in ThreadA, can I read from the device from ThreadB (with a DataReader).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *consent prompt* is a UI, where the user has to confirm permission to use the device. Simplified: As UI can only be modified from the UI thread, that's why you have to call it from there.

After you opened the device, you can use it from any thread.